# I have this problem while building the project in Unreal Engine. Can anyone help me with that

Tags: ios, sdk, unreal-engine4, android-sdk-tools, unreal-development-kit

An error occurred while trying to generate project files.

Some Platforms were skipped due to invalid SDK setup: Mac, IOS, Android, Lumin.
See the log file for detailed information (/Users/sidd/Library/Application Support/Epic/UnrealBuildTool/Log_GPF.txt)

Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
WARNING: Failed to query Xcode version
Triggered an exception while looking for SDK directory in Xcode.app
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs'.
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String path, Boolean ignoreNotFound) at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.Init()
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, Boolean isNormalized, EnumerationOptions options) at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options, Boolean isNormalized)
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.UserDirectories(String directory, String expression, EnumerationOptions options)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths(String path, String searchPattern, SearchTarget searchTarget, EnumerationOptions options)
at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(String path)
at UnrealBuildTool.AppleToolChainSettings.SelectSDK(String BaseSDKDir, String OSPrefix, String& PlatformSDKVersion, Boolean bVerbose) in /Users/build/Build/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/ToolChain/AppleToolChain.cs:line 87
ERROR: Invalid SDK MacOSX.sdk, not found in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

macOS 13.0.1 + Xcode 14.1 + UE5.1 source code

Error:

```
Invalid SDK MacOSX.sdk, not found in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

Fix:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Platforms
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem, [this post](https://community.gamedev.tv/t/ue4-editor-error-when-creating-new-project-on-mac/16311/5) saved my life.

You will need to select a valid 'Command Line Tools' in Xcode Preferences, under Locations tab.

[image]